# MS Word doesn't show on screen

Tags: windows, ms-word, ole, office-automation, ole-automation

My PCs OS are windows 11 and windows 7. I am writing an app that opens a MS Word document by clicking on a file name on a grid (see the screenshot below).

I use the commands:

```
aWordApplication.Visible = True
aWordApplication.Documents.Open(aFileName)
aWordApplication.Activate
```

Doing this, MS Word application runs (see the Word icon on the taskbar on the screenshot).
The problem is that I have to click the word icon to see the actual document. This problem happens on windows 7 and windows 11. But it doesn't happen when I test the app from IDE. I run the App as administrator, it doesn't help either.

Would you please help me to fix the problem, let a document straightly opens on top of windows? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Do you see any problems if you don't open any documents?

Comment: No. All good except this problem.

Comment: Did you try to specify any other document? Do you see the same issue?

Comment: Yes, All word documents have same problem. I run the Process Monitor (Procmon64.exe) to record the processes of running my app in Delphi 6 IDE and running my app directly from windows folder. The I compared the two results and wrote the difference into four text files. But the forum doesn't offer upload file function.

Comment: Where are the documents located?

Comment: the documents are local files.

Comment: Do you get the same picture when you open these files manually?

Comment: If I open manually, the word document shows on screen normally.

Comment: What is the exact file path used in the code?